# How to Run another batch script with ssh.net using c#

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I want to run a batch script when I connect to another computer using ssh.net

It seems it doesn't work:

```
SshCommand command = client.RunCommand("C:\mybatch.bat");
```

I can connect and run a command like `shutdown` but I can't run a batch file.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

try calling script from another drive. Drive C may have need admin permission to access.

```
SshCommand command = client.RunCommand("D:\mybatch.bat");
```

Comment: thank you for quick reply, in the project i call it from another directory, i gave it as an example.